# Order bar chart by another variable in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to build a chart for some LDA scores I have generated from bacterial abundances.

Here an example of the data:

```
Taxa <- c('Bacilli', 'Firmicutes', 'Slackia', 'Clostridium')
Level <- c('Class', 'Phylum', 'Genus', 'Genus')
Status <- c('Patient', 'Patient', 'Control', 'Control')
LDA.score <- c(3.5,2.0,-1,-3)
Example <- data.frame(Taxa, Level, Status, LDA.score)
```

I use this code to make the chart:

```
ggplot(data=Example, aes(x=Taxa, y=LDA.score, fill=Status)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="identity") + coord_flip()
```

I'd like the bars to be in numerical order so that the bars are grouped into control and patient. However, the resulting bar chart is in alphabetical order according to the x axis.

I have attempted to use reorder() but this doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `reorder()` works for me: `ggplot(data=Example, aes(x=reorder(Taxa, LDA.score), y=LDA.score, fill=Status)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="identity") + coord_flip()`

Comment: It suddenly works with `reorder()`. I was trying to apply reorder to the yaxis. Would that explain why it wasn't working?

Comment: Yes---that explains why it wasn't working. Next time, if you show your attempts (e.g., with `reorder()` in this case), it can often help  us help you much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could convert the 'Taxa' to `factor` based on the `order` of 'LDA.score' and then use that in `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
Example %>% 
   mutate(Taxa = factor(Taxa, levels = as.character(Taxa)[order(LDA.score)])) %>% 
   ggplot(., aes(x=Taxa, y=LDA.score, fill=Status)) + 
     geom_bar(stat="identity", position="identity") + 
     coord_flip()
```

-output

[image]

Comment: It works on the example data but I am getting an error with my real data. The real dataset is too large to post on here.  This is the error `Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = as.character(levels)) : 
  factor level [2] is duplicated`

Comment: @Fiona. Okay, I understand the issue here.  You may need to get the `mean` by group in `summarise` before doing the `factor` or uses that in `ggplot` `stat_summary`

Comment: ...or just use `reorder`, which uses `mean` by default. `reorder(Taxa, LDA.score)`